# Installing Joomla 3.x error

Tags: joomla, installation

I'm trying to install Joomla 3.x with MS SERVER. I try to press INSTALL button on last step and it just redirects me to the same place and doesn't actually install anything.

https://img.exs.lv/e/z/ezeliitis/Untitled.png

What could cause this? :/

Answer (score 0):

Have you ensured that all the prerequisites were installed on the application server? This is an old post - but check this: https://docs.joomla.org/Configuring_sqlserver - it should lead you to the right solution.

Comment: I think I've everything, because otherwise I wouldnt be able to choose MSSQL as a  DB (I had to configure it by your mentioned guide).

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you have `max_execution_time=30` in your php.ini file. This means a script can run a max for 30 s. Sometimes database entry takes time gretaer then 30s. So the installation halts. What you need to do is change it to a higher value in your php.ini file. I kept it `max_execution_time=1000`.

Comment: Didn't help. :/

Comment: @Poo123 Did you restart apache server?